# Appium click function is not clicking

Tags: android, selenium, appium, ui-automation

I am automating an Android app. The scenario is like user logins and comes to the page. All previous clicks are working. But when the automation script comes to a page. It does not click the element and doesn't even give an error and switches to the next statement. I don't know what's the issue, either the statement is not getting executed or what else the issue would be. I have 3 classes. One is test class having test methods and the other two having the page objects.

This is my Test Class:

```
public class AppTest{

String appiumPort ="4723";
String serverIp ="0.0.0.0";
LoginPage lPage;
 //static IOSDriver<IOSElement> driver;
public  AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;
ProgrammesPage p_page=null;

 public static URL url;


 @Test(priority=1)

    public void verify() throws MalformedURLException,SocketException  {

     DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability("deviceName", "sALMAN");
        cap.setCapability("udid", "FFY5T18423051220");  
        cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");   
        cap.setCapability("automationName","UiAutomator2");
        cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.0");
        cap.setCapability("appPackage", "uk.org.humanfocus.hfi");   
        cap.setCapability("appActivity", "uk.org.humanfocus.hfi.Home.MainActivity");
        cap.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", "true");
        URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");

        driver = new AppiumDriver<MobileElement>(url,cap);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

         lPage=new LoginPage(driver);
         lPage.validateLoginpage();
          boolean check= lPage.validateLoginpage();

             // = lPage.loginTestCase();

             Assert.assertTrue(check); 

    }


 @Test(priority=2)
 public void verify2()throws SocketException
 {
      lPage=new LoginPage(driver);

        boolean check1=lPage.TestdoLoginWIthValues();

        Assert.assertTrue(check1==true);
 }

 @Test(priority=3)

 public void test3() throws SocketException
    {
        lPage=new LoginPage(driver);

        boolean check1=lPage.loginTestCase();

        Assert.assertTrue(check1==true);

    }

 @Test(priority=4)

 public void test4() throws SocketException
    {
        lPage=new LoginPage(driver);

        boolean check1=lPage.TestGotoHomePage();

        Assert.assertTrue(check1==true);

    }

 @Test(priority=5)

     public void test5() throws InterruptedException, SocketException 
        {
            lPage=new LoginPage(driver);


            boolean check1=lPage.goToTrainings();

            Assert.assertTrue(check1);

        }





 @Test(priority=7)
// @Order(7)
// @DisplayName("Verify that the continue button is not clickable at the first time to start a training")
 public void test7() 
    {
        p_page=new ProgrammesPage(driver);
        boolean check1=p_page.verifyContinueBtnDisable();

        Assert.assertTrue(check1);

    }

 @Test(priority=8)
// @Order(8)
// @DisplayName("Verify that after starting a training the Next button is by default disable in the first section")
 public void test8() 
    {
        p_page=new ProgrammesPage(driver);
        boolean check1=p_page.verifyVideoNextBtnDIsable();
        Assert.assertTrue(check1);

    }
```

}

And this is my programmepage class having elements ids for the page.

```
 public class ProgrammesPage {
    //constructor to initialize ProgrammesPage Class with IOSDriver with 
    pageFactory design pattern
   AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;
   public ProgrammesPage(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver) {
       this.driver = driver;
      // PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
       PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
   }




    //this method verifies that continue button is disabled for the first time 
    public boolean verifyContinueBtnDisable()
    {
        System.out.println("verify methed starts");





        MobileElement el1 = (MobileElement) driver.findElementByXPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.ListView/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.TextView");
        el1.click();


        //driver.findElementById("uk.org.humanfocus.hfi:id/textView_select_code").click();
        //program_code.click();


        System.out.println("Clicked");
        boolean verify=continue_btn.isEnabled();

        if(verify==false)
        {
            verify=true;
        }
        else
        {
            verify=false;
        }
        return verify;

    }

    //@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public boolean verifyVideoNextBtnDIsable()
    {
        program_start_btn.click();
        boolean isElementPresent;
        isElementPresent = video_next_btn.isEnabled();

        if(isElementPresent==false)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }



     /**
        * All elements of this Page are identified below with their respective element locators 
        * element locator like-> by.name , by,xpath, by.id etc
        */


        @FindBy(id = "uk.org.humanfocus.hfi:id/textView_select_code") 
        public MobileElement program_code;

        @FindBy(id = "uk.org.humanfocus.hfi:id/btn_continue")
        public MobileElement continue_btn;


        @FindBy(id = "uk.org.humanfocus.hfi:id/textView_select_title") 
        public MobileElement programme_title;

        @FindBy(xpath = "/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout[2]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.TextView[2]")
        public MobileElement program_code_match;

        @FindBy(id = "uk.org.humanfocus.hfi:id/tv_programme_title")
        public MobileElement programme_title_match;

        @FindBy(id = "uk.org.humanfocus.hfi:id/btn_start")
        public MobileElement program_start_btn;

        @FindBy(xpath = "/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.ImageView[1]")
        public MobileElement video_click_btn;

        @FindBy(id = "uk.org.humanfocus.hfi:id/btn_next")
        public MobileElement video_next_btn;

        @FindBy(name = "Next")
        public MobileElement document_next_btn;





        @FindBy(name = "Yes")
        public MobileElement exit_yes_btn;

        @FindBy(name = "Next")
        public MobileElement question_next_btn;

        //question1
        @FindBy(name = "one way")
        public MobileElement first_question_option_1;

        @FindBy(name = "two way")
        public MobileElement first_question_option_2;

        @FindBy(name = "three way")
        public MobileElement first_question_option_3;


        //questions2 
        @FindBy(name = "Kashif")
        public MobileElement second_question_option_1;

        @FindBy(name = "Murtaza")
        public MobileElement second_question_option_2;

        @FindBy(name = "Bravo")
        public MobileElement second_question_option_3;


        //question3
        @FindBy(name = "this way")
        public MobileElement third_question_option_1;

        @FindBy(name = "that")
        public MobileElement third_question_option_2;

        @FindBy(name = "not now")
        public MobileElement third_question_option_3;

        @FindBy(name = "next day")
        public MobileElement third_question_option_4;




        @FindBy(name = "3")
        public MobileElement total_questions;

        @FindBy(name = "0")
        public MobileElement correct_questions_0;

        @FindBy(name = "1")
        public MobileElement correct_questions_1;

        @FindBy(name = "2")
        public MobileElement correct_questions_2;

        @FindBy(name = "3")
        public MobileElement correct_questions_3;



        @FindBy(name = "Fail")
        public MobileElement fail;

        @FindBy(name = "Pass")
        public MobileElement pass;

        @FindBy(name = "Retake Training")
        public MobileElement retake_training_btn;


   }
```

Comment: which element exactly is not clicking?

Comment: I suggest you test first if XPATH is work using Appium inspector - it has an in inbuilt functionality where u can use  XPATH, Css Locator, accessibilty id, Android UI selector, iOS predicate or iOS class chain. I prefer Android UISelector as it is fast and is more stable.

Comment: I tried xpath, ID and few other in appium inspector. All are working in the there. But when I use them in code it does not work. Even the IDE does not give any error.

Answer (score 0):

First debug the code and check whether respected line is executing or not. If while debugging your code is working then you need to use static or dynamic wait. Also in appium you need to use "TouchAction" class for different gestures instead of normal click function.